# Rules for partial specialization of templates with nontype parameter(s)

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Consider the following template

```cpp
template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&x);
```

and I want to specialize it for some class `A`. Here is my try (by referring to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)):

```cpp
template <int v> void func<A, v>(const A&x);
```

However, that's illegal. My question is why this is illegal (which rule it breaks) and if that is against the grammar, is there other ways for us to specialize it for `A`?

Comment: you can do `template <int v> void func(const A&x);`

Comment: @appleapple But isn't this creating another template?

Comment: what's the difference? can you show how you'd like to use it?

Comment: You cannot **partial** specialize **functions**. See [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates): *"partial specializations are only allowed for class templates [and variable templates (since C++14)]."*

Comment: BTW better to reverse template parameter order as `T` is deducible: `template <int v, typename T> void func(const T&x);` to allow call such as `func<42>(my_obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function templates cannot be partially specialized, hence the error:

```
<source>:8:23: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization 'func<A, v>' is not allowed
    8 | template <int v> void func<A, v>(const A&x);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

You can for example partially specialize a type with `operator()`:

```
template <typename T, int v>
struct func{
    void operator()(const T&x);
};

struct A {};

template <int v> 
struct  func<A, v>{
    void operator()(const A&x);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I also thought of the possibility of using a functional object, and I will try that!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot partially specialize a function template but you can **overload** it as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
class A 
{
    
};

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&x) //primary template
{
    std::cout<<"primary template"<<std::endl;
}
//this is an overload and not a specialization. Also partial specialization cannot be done for function templates
template <int v> void func(const A&x)
{
    std::cout<<"overload not specialization"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    func<int, 5>(84); //uses primary template 
    
    func<5>(A()); //uses the overloaded version
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Realize `v` is not deduced here, which may cause undesired effect, leave this here as it maybe useful for someone reach this question.

---

you can do it with

```
template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&x);
template <int v> void func(const A&x);
```

---

as for why, I think it mainly because it provide no additional value

```
template <typename T> void func(const T&x);
template <typename T> void func(const T*x);
void func(const A&);
```

is already a valid function *"specialization"*. *<sub>not really specialization in the sense of standard wording</sub>*

Comment: You are wrong. The last 2 versions which you're calling specialization are overloads.

Comment: @AanchalSharma I'm not calling them specialization, that's why I quote them and use Italic

Comment: `is already a valid function "specialization".` This seems to me you're calling them specialization. Maybe you can write it more clearly what you mean so that there is no confusion.

Comment: @AanchalSharma added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraint (or SFINAE) to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {};
class B {};

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&)
{
    std::cout<<"generic";
}

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&)
requires std::is_same_v<T,A>
{
    std::cout<<"A";
}

int main(){
    func<A,1>(A{}); // output A
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YcxeoofYE